# Good source to learn about the differences between ATI and NVIDIA in OpenGL rendering?

Tags: c++, opengl, nvidia

The more i learn about OpenGL, the more problems i find!

All i need is a list of the most common problems between ATI/NVIDIA cards, with solutions.

So where is this magical source?

Comment: Magical source is OpenGL driver developers themselves. Of course that means you have to had some kind of partnership with the IHVs (if you're an ISV it's maybe the case). Otherwise, yes you can try NeHe, OpenGL.org forums or maybe GameDev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately try it and discuss it on the NeHe and OpenGL forums.
There are no real official lists and the bugs and mis-implemented features differ from card-card and with operating system.

Comment: It would be helpful to all of us working on graphics APIs if we could find a mostly complete list of problems. Would this be a good wiki topic?